# Creation of an organization chart?

Tags: mobile, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I'd like to know how to create an interactive flowchart like the one shown in the following images using PowerApps.
I would like to be able to display for each person in charge, his team underneath and thus put the person in charge on which I clicked previously at the top of the block and have his team underneath.

I am trying to create this flowchart by going through the data in my SharePoint list.

Screen before clicking on manager (basic screen) :

[image]

Screen after clicking on manager 1 :

[image]

Hoping to make you understand

I'd like him to make me an organization chart to sort the employees according to their rank in the company and the teams they're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power Apps canvas apps, you could do that using a Container with Labels for the manager and a gallery of similar controls for subordinates.

You said you wanted to map the organization using a SharePoint list, but you could also use the [Office365Users connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/) for this purpose. When you click 'Manager1', you could run the 'Get direct reports (V2)' and display the results in the gallery. Also, you must save the object for 'Manager1' in a variable and set up the BOSS area so that it displays this variable.

I suggest you also implement a button to enable users move across the organization upwards.

Comment: And how do I do all this? 
Is there a detailed tutorial on the Internet?

And knowing that if I use office365Users Connector no hierarchy is made in Office365.

I'm a beginner on PowerApps and frankly I find this setup extremely complex.

Comment: Office365 has a 'manager' field for users so implicitly there is a hierarchy. While the above description may seem complex, it is actually much better than maintaining already existing information duplicated in a SharePoint list and deal with delegation. Perhaps this video explains more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sb6xALH1NQc